# Algorithm to find minimum number of resistors from a set of resistor values. (C++ or Python)

Tags: python, c++, algorithm

I'm trying to design an algorithm that takes in a resistance value and outputs the minimum number of resistors and the values associated with those resistors. I would like the algorithm to iterate through a set of resistor values and the values in the set can be used no more than n times. I would like some direction on where to start.

Series: Req = R1 + R2 +...

Parallel: (1/Req) = (1/R1) + (1/R2)  +...

**Input:**

*100000 (100k)*

**Set:** {30k, 50k, 80k, 200k}

**Output:**

*2 resistors in series: 50k + 50k*

*2 resistors in parallel: 200k || 200k*

Comment: This looks like a combinatorial optimization problem.  There are entire textbooks for this, not really something that can be explained in a single StackOverflow answer.    It looks to me a bit like a variation of the [Backpack Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), but way harder due to the parallel alternate.

Comment: FWIW, this seems like a job for [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) if you can figure out how to break it into sub-problems.  It is a fairly advanced technique.

Comment: I wonder if you could set up a concept of a "virtual resistor" to model the parallel case (also recording the number of resistors consumed and which ones), then reduce the problem to the series case.

Comment: ...no more than `n` times... Is that also an input?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem, which is fine by itself. But you should work on solving it yourself, not just ask for help with the entire problem. A homework problem like this would not be assigned without suitable prerequisite lessons. Then questions that would be appropriate for Stack Overflow would be specific questions about applying techniques you were taught earlier to this problem, or other specific questions about implementation.

Comment: I've voted to reopen, based on the *algorithm* tag.  OP grasps a simple case, but may be overwhelmed by the combinatorial explosion of the search space.  Prior comments are good leads.

Comment: The basic concepts of a good algorithm to solve this problem are not very difficult, once we know it. I understood it is what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually quite hard, best I can do is propose an idea for an algorithm for solving the first part, the concept of including parallels looks harder as well, but maybe the algorithm can be extended.

If you define a function "best", which takes a target resistance as input and outputs the minimal set of resistors that generates that resistance. E.G: if you only had 10K resistors, best(50K)=5*10K.

This function "best" has the following properties for a set of available resistors [A, B, C,...]:

1. best(A) = A for any A in the set.
2. best(Target) = min(best(Target-A) + A), best(Target-B) + B,...)
3. best(0)=0
4. best(x)=nonsense, if x<0 (remove these cases)

This can be used to reductively solve the problem. (I'd probably recommend storing the variables down the tree as you go along.

Here's an example to illustrate a bit:

---

AvailableSet = [10K, 100K]

Target = 120K

**First iteration:**

best(120K) = min[ best(110K) + 10K, best(20K) + 100K]

**calculate each subtree:**

best(110K) = min[best(100K) + 10K, best(10K) + 100K]

This is now finalised as we can calculate everything in the min(_) by using the properties, so work back up the tree:
best(110K) = 100K + 10K ( I suppose if there is a tie like in this case pick a permuation randomly)

best(120K) = min[best(110K) + 10K , best(20K) + 100K] = ... = 100K + 10K + 10K

That should work as a solution to the first half of the problem, you may be able to extend this by adding extra properties, but it will make it harder to solve the problem reductively in this way.

Probably the best way is to solve this first half of the problem and use a different algorithm to find the best solution using parallels and decide which is minimal in each case.